# Get parameter from URL on aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, parameters

How can I get parameter from URL on aspx page?

I have an application which has parameter `?id=12345abcd` and I want to get this id to select command in my gridview

```
 SelectCommand="SELECT [a], [b], [c], [d], [e], [f], [g], [h], [c] FROM [table] WHERE [c] = parameterFromUrl"
```

And insert this id from url inside variable `paramterFromUrl` in query.

Answer (score 5):

You can access that `Id` by looking at the `Request.QueryString` property in your code. For your use case, in the code behind, access that Id like:

```
string Id= Request.QueryString["id"].ToString();
```

And use it in your `SelectCommand` as:

```
SelectCommand="SELECT [a], [b], [c], [d], [e], [f], [g], [h], [c] FROM [table] WHERE [c] =" + Id;
```

**Please be aware of sql injection**

Comment: to avoid sql injection use ToString("'", "''")

Comment: By doing the `.ToString()`, if the parameter is missing you get a nice exception...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
sqlCommand.CommandText = "SELECT [a], [b], [c], [d], [e], [f], [g], [h], [c] FROM [table] WHERE [c] = @ParameterFromUrl";
sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ParameterFromUrl", Request.QueryString["id"].ToString());
```